# Matching elements in two equal-sized lists so that the pairs of elements have similar values

Tags: python

For lists

```
l1 = [2.5, 1.1, 3.6]
l2 = [3.4, 1.0, 2.2]
```

how to sort l2 efficiently to

```
l2_sorted = [2.2, 1.0, 3.4]
```

so that Sum_i(l2_sorted[i] - l1[i])^2 is minimum?

There is a context for this question: the three complex roots, root_A, root_B, and root_C for the polynomial function x^3 + a x^2 + b x + c = 0 vary continuously with the parameters a, b, and c in the complex plane, and I want to keep track which root is which when varying the parameters. Simply sorting them each time according to their locations doesn't work because their trajectories (series of locations when continuously varying the parameters) can cross each other.

The actual problem is a much higher-order polynomial with a large number of roots, making it hard to track them manually.

Comment: Did you repost this question without making any changes? The last time this was closed for needing more focus, which you have failed to do.

Comment: What if you have `l1 = [2.5, 1.1, 2.5]`? or `l1 = [2.2, 3.4, 5]`?

Comment: Please don't [re-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77652684/3001761).

Comment: I've changed the order of the numbers in the list and added the criterion for "similar" @B Remmelzwaal. Whatever order that minimizes the sum of square differences will be preferred @mozway.

Comment: I won't re-post this time, but what do you do when your question, which you think is a meaningful one, gets closed without getting an answer? @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 0):

OK here's a working, but not very efficient (for large lists) answer:

```
def sorted_match_sim(l1, l2):
    l1 = np.array(l1)
    l2perms = [np.array(list(i)) for i in itertools.permutations(l2)]
    dist_perm = np.array([(abs(l1 - l2perm)**2).sum() for l2perm in l2perms])
    l2_sel = l2perms[dist_perm.argmin()]
    return l2_sel
```

```
>>> sorted_match_sim(l1, l2) 
array([2.2, 1. , 3.4])
```